# copy from net's data to logic's data or make data as a class member

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using unity3d to develop a network game with ProtoBuff.

I define a BattleData.proto

```
message BattleData
{
    required uint64  id = 1;
    required string  name = 2;
    required int32   hp  = 3;  
    required int32   atk  = 4;  
}
```

I recv data from net and deserialize the binary data to the class BattleData.

now I have a problem about how to use it.

If make data as a class member, I should use logic.battleData.XXX, otherwise I can use logic.atk as faster.

I don't like the style one, because here is so many '.' , but if I 
choose another, I must modify the class`BattleLogic` when the proto changed.

```cs
public class BattleLogic{
    public BattleData battleData;
 or???
    public ulong id;
    public string name;
    public int hp;
    public int atk;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you just don't like the `.` you could simply use [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) like

```
public class BattleLogic
{
    public BattleData battleData;

    // as expression body
    public ulong id 
    {
        get 
        {
            return battleData.id; 
        }
        set 
        {
            battleData.id = value; 
        }
    }
    // basically the same as expression bodies
    public string name { get => battleData.name; set => battleData.name = value; }
    public int hp { get => battleData.hp; set => battleData.hp = value; }
    public int atk { get => battleData.atk; set => battleData.atk = value; }
}
```

Now you can read and write

```
var id = battleLogicReference.id;
battleLogicReference.name = "XYZ";
```

Comment: Well yes it's this or an additional `.` access everytime you access it